# Inheritance in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

Why doesn't `jordan` have the properties of the `Human` class? Shouldn't saying `Coder.prototype = new Human;` be enough for all `Coder` classes to inherit all properties of the `Human` class?

Does it have something to do with defining functions as assignments?

```
var Human = function() {
     var hi = function() {
         alert('hi');
      };
     return {
        name : 'dan',
       sayHi : hi
     };
};

var dan = new Human();

var Coder = function() {
   var code = function() {
      alert('1010101');
   };    
  return {
    code : code
  };
};

Coder.prototype = new Human;
Coder.prototype.constructor = new Coder;
var jordan = new Coder();
console.log(jordan);
```

Comment: Is there a reason your trying to hide the vars code and hi?

Comment: Just need to say that inheritance in JavaScript `works well`. Your code isn't working.

Comment: @pkuderov great contribution.

Comment: @KevinBowersox, not a real example just trying to understand how it actually inherits. I'd like to be able to private scope vars, but I can do that by not attaching them to this i guess.

Comment: For more info on prototype, inheritance, overriding and calling super you can have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 You don't have create a new instance of the parent to inherit and in the child's body it's better to call something like `Parent.call(this,arguments);` to make the parent's instance variables part of the to be constructed child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a funny thing: a JS constructor can return an object that becomes this. This object however doesn't follow the prototypes, as defined for the constructor (in this case it's a plain `Object`). The correct way that looks like your code would be:

```
var Human = function() {
    var hi = function() {
        alert('hi');
    };
    this.name = "dan";
    this.sayHi = hi;
};

// or even:
var Human = function() {
    this.name = "dan";
};

Human.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    alert('hi');
};
```

Similar for `Coder`. The inheritance code is OK.

Comment: ahhhh, i knew it had to do with that, but why is it that I can't have a function redefine it's this. I was hoping to follow my typical alias returning of a function but still be able to prototype. Is there a workaround? can I explicitly define the constructor?

Comment: No, I don't think there is :)

Comment: The inheritance code is *almost* okay: the part that adjusts the constructor should be `Coder.prototype.constructor = Coder;`

Answer (score 2):

Your constructors do not return the objects they're creating, so inheritance won't work. Use this instead:

```
var Human = function() {
     this.sayHi = function() {
         alert('hi');
     };
     this.name = 'dan';
};

var dan = new Human();

var Coder = function() {
   this.code = function() {
      alert('1010101');
   };    
};

Coder.prototype = new Human;
Coder.prototype.constructor = Coder;
var jordan = new Coder();
console.log(jordan);
```

Another option, moving the stuff from `Human` to the prototype:

```
var Human = function() {};
Human.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    alert('hi');
};
Human.prototype.name = 'dan'; // will be shadowed if redefined on instances

var Coder = function() {};
Coder.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Coder.prototype.code = function() {
    alert('1010101');
};  
var jordan = new Coder();
console.log(jordan);
```

A polyfill for `Object.create` is [available on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: i was hoping to use my standard aliasing at the end of a function. is there no work around? adding the function to the prototype is def better and more efficient way!

Comment: There's no way use prototypes and return a completely new object at the same time. Maybe you could just use Object.create directly? Something like: `var extendedObj = Object.create(baseObj)`, without using constructors (you could wrap that in a function, of course, but wouldn't be calling it with `new`).